# SQL query to return all columns from table, but with a max of 3 duplicate id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone please lend a hand with this query? I've been fooling with LIMIT or TOP, but I think I'm off track. I want to return all fields from a table, but with a max of 3 duplicate id's in the new table.

**Table**

```
id    first    last    
===================
1    John    Doe    
1    John    Doe   
1    John    Doe   
1    John    Doe   
2    Mary    Green  
2    Mary    Green  
3    Stacy   Kirk  
3    Stacy   Kirk  
3    Stacy   Kirk  
3    Stacy   Kirk  
3    Stacy   Kirk
```

**Desired Results (up to 3 ids)**

```
id    first    last  
====================
1    John     Doe  
1    John     Doe  
1    John     Doe  
2    Mary     Green  
2    Mary     Green  
3    Stacy    Kirk  
3    Stacy    Kirk  
3    Stacy    Kirk
```

Thanks!

Comment: since your talking about `limit` I can presume your talking about `mySQL`? or at least not `mssql`

Comment: Ooops, no LIMIT in mssql is there?  :)  No wonder it didn't like my query.  Yes, I'm using mssql.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

since you mentioned `TOP`, this is for `SQL SERVER`

```
SELECT id, first, last
FROM
  (
  SELECT id, first, last,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LAST) rn
  FROM TABLE1
  ) s
WHERE s.rn <= 3
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo** (*SQL Server*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08ccd/1)

Comment: Thanks John, but running the above returns three rows of John Doe only.  I want up to three, so that's good, but for all ID's.

Comment: what do you mean by for all id?

Comment: In my sample table above, I have ID's 1,2,3.  When I ran your code, it only returned ID 1, John Doe, three times.  I want to return all ID's, but limit the duplicate ID's to a max of three.  See the Desired Results table above.

Comment: i'm a little confused honestly, how was the result result from fiddle differed from your result above? or maybe if you have IDs 1-10, do you only want to return 1-3?

Comment: Oh, I didn't click on the fiddle link before, those results are exactly what I want!  But that's not what's happening when I run the same query in SQL server.  I'm only getting John Doe.  My data types are all varchar, would that make a difference?

Comment: @Caddy absolutely not, maybe you have missed any detail, are the tables the same with your original one? how about the data? I've change to varchar and still its working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0de82/1

Comment: Strange.  I'm using MSSQL 2008 R2.  I copied and pasted the exact code from fiddle, creating the table, then running the query, and it only returns John Doe.  Thanks for trying to help, Mr Woo, I don't know what's going on.  ;)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong on your server.. hehe I tested the query on my machine with SQL Server 2008 and 2012 installed and they are working fine :D